# pointer inside round brackets

Tags: c, pointers, brackets

```
void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* allocate node */
    struct node* new_node =
            (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    /* put in the data  */
    new_node->data  = new_data;

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);   

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}
```

If i remember correctly, putting a brackets on a pointer means calling a function?
If that's true i don't really understand why there are brackets on *head_ref.
Id love a little explanation on why do i need brackets on `*head_ref` in this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case, the brackets are serving no purpose other than to clarify the programmer's intent, i.e. they they want to dereference `head_ref`.

Note that `head_ref` is a pointer to a pointer, so in this case, `new_node->next` is being set to point to the original head of the linked list, and then the pointer pointed to by `head_ref` is being updated to point to `new_node` which is now the start of the list.

As Michael Krelin has pointed out below, putting brackets around a pointer do not mean it's a calling a function, or a pointer to a function. If you saw this: `(*head_ref)()` **then** it would be a call to the function pointed to by `head_ref`.

Comment: +1 and no, brackets around a pointer doesn't mean calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function will look something like that:

```
(*some_func_pointer)();
```

The parenthesis in your case are meaningless.

Also, no need to cast the result of `malloc` (`void*`) in C.

Answer (score 1):

Its simply dereferencing the pointer over here in your case.

the one you said : **"putting a brackets on a pointer means calling a function"**

is true in case what follows after the * is a function pointer.
basically it depends on the type of the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

These brackets are just for grouping.

To call a function by a pointer to it:

```
(* funcPointer)(param1,param2)
^             ^^         ^
|             |`---------`--- These brackets tell the compiler 
|             |               it's a function call
|             |
`-------------`---------------These brackets just group the * 
                              with the variable name
```

For a function that takes no parameters, it would just be `()`

Your example doesn't have a pair of brackets after the variable, so it's not a function call.